# application with sapui5 and openui5

Tags: sapui5

Actually we have developed on application with sapui5 for our customer but the problem is that some new customer dont want to go through License agrement with sapui5. So the solution we have found to make our application with openui5.
My question is that

"Is there any possibility to make application with both of them and at the time of installation making a decision either going and make resources of sapui5 or openui5"?

Thank you
Nimi

Answer (score 4):

As long as you understand that certain features will only be available in SAPUI5 you can **load the version of sap-ui-core.js that comes with either in your bootstrap index.html page**.

For example, if using CDN, for OpenUI5 link to https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js and for SAPUI5 use https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js

See [this link](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2013/12/11/what-is-openui5-sapui5) to read about differences between SAPUI5 and OpenUI5.
Also see [this link](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5982a9734748474aa8d4af9c3d8f31c0.html) for another discussion of the differences.

Answer (score 1):

I know that [this post](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/12/11/what-is-openui5-sapui5/) (I'm linking to) is not so much updated but it will give you a good overview and history about SAPUI5/OpenUI5 and all the differences.

Anyway, SAPUI5 is a superset of OpenUI5 with some addictional control (like VizChart or FilterBar.

I think that in 90% of cases you can just go with OpenUI5 and use other opensource libraries / develop custom control if you need something that is missing.